# How to create a HTML form default phrase that is not editable by the user?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to add some logic to an HTML form field.

In my project I'm having users create a title in their submission forms. One of the form fields is `"Title"` where users can type in their own custom title. I wanted to force the phrase `"#KICK..."` in the form field and have it so that users will not be able to delete it and will have to write their custom titles after the phrase `"#KICK..."`.

I've been trying to figure out where I might go to learn about how to do something like this but haven't been able to track anything down. Would love to be pointed in the right direction or hear what someone might do to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no in-built way to add a prefix to a form element. But, you can work around it using Javascript or CSS.

Here's a CSS only way ..

```css
div { position: relative }
div:before {
    align-items: center;
    content: '#KICK...';
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 7px;
    position: absolute;
}

input {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    padding-left: 68px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input>
</div>
```

Play around with `margin-left` and `padding-left` to get it right for your existing styles.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used a variation of what you used here.

Answer (score 0):

You can place up a `div` element with `position:absolute`over the input field like follows:

```css
.field-with-kick {position: relative}
.field-with-kick div
{
    top: 2px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

.field-with-kick input {padding-left: 66px}
```

```html
<div class="field-with-kick">
    <input placeholder="placeholder for title">
    <div>#KICK...</div>
</div>
```